# Has anyone else noticed the new review queue?

Tags: discussion, reviewing

Recently, I was doing my question sweep and noted late posts was overdue for a review. When I opened it, it looked **much different**! Has a change been made on SE, *or is this an opt-in the arqade SE opted into?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, the redesign is part of a wider overhaul of the Review queues that the Stack Exchange team have been (and continue to) work on. See this post on Meta SE for more information: [Visual design changes to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360198/179041).*

It's not something we had to sign up or 'opt in' for - as per the rollout plan at the top of that post, on Feb 23 the design was shipped to all network sites.

---

<sub>* The question is marked [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) which usually means that it would be displayed in the yellow announcements widget on the right of the page, but I guess we have so many active Meta posts on Arqade at the moment that it isn't currently showing up there.</sub>

Comment: Since it's a featured meta post on Meta StackExchange, it appears under a different box than hot Arqade meta posts. So it's always been visible for me on the main site at least. Doesn't appear to be visible on Meta Arqade

Comment: Huh! I didnt see it, thanks for telling me. 
I do like the new queue doe, looks more smooth